# DevExpress Accelerator Keys not showing in xtraBars

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress 2010 vol 1, VS2010 and VB.NET.

In my form I have a xtraBar which is used to create the application main menu. Each of the menu items were carefully captioned using the ampersand char (&) to create the keyboard accelerator key, so when user presses <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and hits the accelerator key the menu is shown.

The problem is I can't make the underscore show in any caption. For instance, my first menu "File" has caption "&File", but the "F" is never underscore, and pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't work either.

After googling for some time, I tried to change the Appearance/TextOptions/HotkeyPrefix to **Show** of my MainMenu Bar. This didn't work. Also, changing MenuAppearance/Menu or MenuBar or MenuCaption/TextOptions/HotkeyPrefix of the MenuBarItem to **Show** does not fix the problem.

I'm pretty aware that MS Windows has an accessibility setting to hide underscore over menu captions, and I'm absolutely sure that this option is disabled in my system.

Comment: That must be a bug with 2010V1...have you tried running the app on a second machine?....all my apps have the "_" where expected, however, I am using 2009 v3...I have a 2010 on another machine will check in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

From Windows XP onwards, Windows hides these accessibility underscores by default; this may be the problem you're having.  The shortcut should still work, though.

To get Windows XP to show the accessibility underscores all the time, go to 'Display Properties | Appearance | Effects', and uncheck "Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key."

In Windows 7, you must go to 'Control Panel (Category view) | Ease of Access | Change how your keyboard works' and check 'Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys'.

Hope that helps!

Comment: -1 As I stated in my question I'm pretty sure that this feature is disabled in my OS.